# Django: migrate Table 'forum_user' already exists

Tags: django, django-south, migrate

I have changed the Django models, and I use the Django `schemamigration` to update the database. But, when I do `python manager.py migrate app`， it throws this error message：

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'forum_user' already exists")
```

Comment: Then the table that django south is trying to create already exists and doesn't match the state of your database. If this is the first time you're migrating, remember that before you make schemamigration changes, you must set the initial state and `migrate app --fake` to match the database to the south database state

Comment: how to set the initial state ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Then the table that django south is trying to create already exists and doesn't match the state of your database.

If this is the first time you're migrating, remember that before you make schemamigration changes, you must set the initial state via `schemamigration myapp --initial` and `migrate app --fake` to match the database to the south database state.

`manage.py convert_to_south myapp` also does the above as a convenience method.

#### To start using south...

1. Make sure your django tables match your current database tables exactly - if you planned to add or remove columns, comment those out.
2. Run python manage.py schemamigration myapp --initial
3. Run python manage.py migrate myapp --fake
4. Make changes to your django model
5. Run python manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto
6. Run python manage.py migrate myapp

## Update

Note django 1.7+ ships with migrations and south is no longer in use.

There are only two commands worth noting..

- manage.py makemigrations (handles --initial)
- manage.py migrate

Written by the same author as South, crowd funded. Go django.

Comment: This deserves way more up votes than it's got, valuable information and really helped.

Comment: After reading multiple tutorials, your answer was the one which helped me fix my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed a duplicate table issue locally and wanted to document my workflow to help others.

The key to success was creating an `--empty` migration before the new models are added. The flow:

- Merged in another persons work that excluded info on a model I have locally.
- normal `schemamigration --auto` was adding a table/model again and caused "already exists error".
- Solved by commenting out the new model and running an empty migration via `clear; python manage.py schemamigration --empty APPNAME MIGRATION_FILE_NAME`. This creates a "declaration" of the state of the models with no forward/backwards commands. Be 100% sure the current state of models (python files) and database are in sync!!! This most current migration will be used for the creation of a differential to migrate correctly (next).
- uncomment the new model and run `clear; python manage.py schemamigration APPNAME --auto` to create the true and desired differential off (uses the `--empty` migration just created). The new migration will have forward/backward commands that should be appropriate for your new model. Review...
- finish off with `clear; python manage.py migrate`

The lesson learned is that `--auto` looks at the last APP+migration file to create a forward/backwards diff. If the last migration does NOT have in the dictionary a model you have in DB it will be created again causing an "already exists" error. Think of the dictionary as a contract between Django and the DB stating "here's what everything should look like". The migration can include commands that create duplicate tables and will only be exposed during ```migrate`` command.

The above info should fix the problem. Presented in part to help people and also for review in case I am doing something foolish.